# checked the Return the value of ratiobutton from gridview using select command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

net C# 
and I'm using radiobutton (MALE and FEMALE) now I can get the value of my two radiobutton and save to database 
and I'm using datagridview and what I want is when I select the row from datagrid and when I select a person's name age and gender it will show  to the textbox and edit it .. I can save the name and age but not the gender because I'm using the radio button.. I tried to use `male_b.checked=true;` but it doesn't work

here's my code

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

        T_firstName.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Firstname") as Label).Text;
        T_middlename.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Middlename") as Label).Text;
        T_lastname.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Lastname") as Label).Text;
        T_age.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Age") as Label).Text;
        ID_label.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label).Text;
        string gender= (row.FindControl("lbl_Sex") as Label).Text;
        if (gender == "MALE")
        {
            male_b.Checked = true; 
        }
        else if (gender=="FEMALE")
        {
            female_b.Checked = true; 
        } 
    }
```

that's the only problem.. thank you

Comment: "but it doesn't work" why? any exception?@JapsDeLuna

Answer (score 1):

If `lbl_Sex` is RadioButton, I think this line

```
 string gender= (row.FindControl("lbl_Sex") as Label).Text;
```

Should be

```
string gender= (row.FindControl("lbl_Sex") as RadioButton).Content;
```

and then:

```
    if (gender == "MALE")
    {
        male_b.IsChecked=true;

    }
    else if (gender=="FEMALE")
    {
        female_b.IsChecked=true;
    }
```

Hope helps!

Comment: sir thank you for trying but '.content' and '.IsChecked' are not working in ASP.net C#  :'(